# install php5.6 in debian9

Tags: debian, php-5.6

i tried to install php5.6 in the debian9. i am not able to install
i am getting below error

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: libdb5.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libonig2 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
                       Depends: apache2-mpm-prefork but it is not installable or
                                apache2-mpm-itk but it is not installable
                       Depends: php5-cli but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.